# Using JavaScript or JQuery how do I determine when a DOM element is added to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

An external JavaScript adds a DOM element to a page.

Using JavaScript or JQuery how do I determine when this DOM element is added to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have three choices, one of which isn't available on all browsers:

1. Get a notification from the other script that it's added an element (if it provides one)
2. Poll (I'd use `setTimeout` and reschedule each following check on purpose) to see if the element appears. E.g.:

   ```
   var CHECK_INTERVAL = 100; 100 = 1/10th second, choose appropriate 
   function checkForElement() {
       /* ...check for the element... */
       if (/*...you found the element...*/) {
           // Do something with it
       }
       else {
           // Check again after a brief pause
           setTimeout(checkForElement, CHECK_INTERVAL);
       }
   }
   setTimeout(checkForElement, CHECK_INTERVAL);
   ```
3. Use a [mutation observer](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/), which is the replacement for the broken old mutation events. This lets you register a callback to be called on certain mutation events. [Support is reasonable](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) but — quelle shock — IE didn't get them until IE11.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to that external javascript file, you can just call a function in your page from that file just after you add an element. If you don't have this facility or there is not event triggering in between, you can keep on checking existence of such element in a certain interval using javascript setInterval() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var chekElement = function (){

    // this will rerun function every second
    var chekElemRecursiveTimer = setTimeout(chekElement, 1000);

    var someElement = $('.someElement');
    if (someElement){
        alert("its on page!");
        clearTimeout(chekElemRecursiveTimer);
    }

}

// run function in page or from external js file
chekElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to checked this

```
var chekForElement = function (){

    var chekElementTimer = setTimeout(chekForElement, 1000);

    if ($('.chcekedElementclass').length > 0){
        alert("found in page");
        clearTimeout(chekElemRecursiveTimer);
    }

}

// run function in page or from external js file
chekForElement();
```